# Is there any way to find out certificate exception from Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I have used Volley network library for making API calls. From the application, it will call the APIs with the server with valid certificate only i.e. no code written to by pass the certificate validation. I have given it to customer and he is trying to test it and that environment is not accessible for me.

When customer tries the app, the server URL is accessible from the chrome browser but not from the app. I assume that since the app only able to communicate with the server with valid certificate, it is not able to make connection. In this case, Volley simply returns the error object as Timeout error and no other information.

Is there any way to find out exact cause of the issue? I need information from Volley like its because server doesn't have valid certificate installed or something else in more detailed text.

Anyone knows how to get this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you see any exception like `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`?? https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl

Comment: @Raghunandan No. Simply getting timeout error.